# Finding a unique url from a large list of URLs in O(n) time in a single pass

Tags: c++, python, algorithm

Recently I was asked this question in an interview. I gave an answer in O(n) time but in two passes. Also he asked me how to do the same if the url list cannot fit into the memory. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: can you provide more details? are you supposed to find a specific url? or unique ones in a list that might have duplicate ones?

Comment: What does "a unique url" mean? A given URL that appears only once on the list? Or at least one URL that appears on the list exactly once? The one and only URL that appears on the list exactly once without being given that URL?

Comment: unique url means it appears exactly once in the list

Comment: Curious about the "url list cannot fit into the memory": I don't think I could go out and buy a machine with less than 4gb RAM.

Comment: Would also be nice to see your answer

Comment: I just used a python dictionary and used url as key into dictionary and counted no of occurrences of each url. Now in second pass I iterated through dict to get count.

Comment: Maybe hashing the URLs could save you some space if the complete URL list does not fit in memory.

Comment: @JonClements: Micro instances on AWS have about a half-gig, and you can buy PRGMR slices down to 64 MiB.

Comment: For the "cannot fit in memory" case, I assume it would be "cheating" to use files or other forms of external storage, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it all fits in memory, then the problem is simple: Create two sets (choose your favorite data structure), both initially empty. One will contain unique URLs and the other will contain URLs that occur multiple times. Scan the URL list once. For each URL, if it exists in the unique set, remove it from the unique set and put it in the multiple set; otherwise, if it does not exist in the multiple set, add it to the unique set.

If the set does not fit into memory, the problem is difficult. The requirement of O(n) isn't hard to meet, but the requirement of a "single pass" (which seems to exclude random access, among other things) is tough; I don't think it's possible without some constraints on the data. You can use the set approach with a size limit on the sets, but this would be easily defeated by unfortunate orderings of the data and would in any event only have a certain probability (<100%) of finding a unique element if one exists.

EDIT:

If you can design a set data structure that exists in mass storage (so it can be larger than would fit in memory) and can do find, insert, and deletes in O(1) (amortized) time, then you can just use that structure with the first approach to solve the second problem. Perhaps all the interviewer was looking for was to dump the URLs into a data base with a UNIQUE index for URLs and a count column.

Comment: if they don't fit in memory, a persistent hashtable would help

Comment: @FelicePollano - Yep, just what I was writing as your comment came up on my screen. :)

Comment: @FelicePollano - However, I don't know of a persistent hashtable implementation that supports O(1) operations. Without that, it can be used to satisfy the single pass requirement, but not the O(n) requirement. The best I would know how to do is O(n log n).

Comment: Agree with the db solution you propose, is this satisfying the complexity constraint ?

Answer (score 2):

One could try to use Trie structure for keeping data. It's compressed so it would take less memory, as memory reusage for common url parts.

loop would look like:

```
add string s to trie;
check that added string is not finished in existing node
    internal node -> compress path
    leaf node -> delete path
```

Comment: I wonder if it meets the complexity requirement though. Insertion in a Trie (or Patricia Tree or whatever custom version) is not strictly O(1), is it ?

Comment: I know it's O(s), where s = length of inserted string.

MM, do you think the proposed algorithm is O(n)?

_I just used a python dictionary and used url as key into dictionary and counted no of occurrences of each url. Now in second pass I iterated through dict to get count. – mousey 11 hours ago_

So we have to either forget about such minor things, either we have to pay attention to every detail.

Answer (score 0):

For the "fits-in-memory" case, you could use two hash-tables as follows (pseudocode):

```
hash-table uniqueTable = <initialization>;
hash-table nonUniqueTable = <initialization>;
for-each url in url-list {
    if (nonUniqueTable.contains(url)) {
        continue;
    }
    else if (uniqueTable.contains(url)) {
        nonUniqueTable.add(url);
        uniqueTable.remove(url);
    }
    else {
        uniqueTable.add(url)
    }
}
if (uniqueTable.size() > 1)
    return uniqueTable.first();
```

Comment: And if the data don't fit into memory?

Comment: @Ted Hopp:  I don't think it can be done in a single pass, although I haven't been able to "prove" that yet.  (And yeah, while the above solution does not store *all* of the URLs, storing only one instance of each multiple URL, I doubt it counts as a general solution to the second question.)

Answer (score 0):

**Python based**

You have a `list` - not sure where it's "coming" from, but if you already have it in memory then:

```
L.sort()
from itertools import groupby
for key, vals in groupby(L, lambda L: L):
    if len(vals) == 1:
       print key
```

Otherwise use storage (possibly using):

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('somefile')
db.execute('create table whatever(key)')
```

Get your data into that, then execute "select * from whatever group by key where count(*) = 1)"

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a classic interview question and the answer they were expecting was that you first sort the urls and then make a binary search.
If it doesn't fit in memory, you can do the same thing with a file.

Comment: Good point, although your approach will still require more than one pass.

Comment: that would be something I'd debate with the interviewer because I'm not entirely sure the sorting of the urls is something that should be taken into account as this is most likely static data and should be stored that way, but if it does then you can include the url you are trying to find into the sort, find its position and then look to the left and right to see if there's another one like it in the list

Comment: But Radix sort itself will require multiple passes here.